# Text box inside a GridView in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, gridview, mvvm

How to bind textbox inside WPF  Grid View to a property in view model? I am using MVVM pattern.

```
<ListView Canvas.Left="135" Canvas.Top="185" Height="204" Name="listView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=lstSelectedStocks}" Width="436" >
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>

                            <GridViewColumn Header="SI No." DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Index}"  Width="80"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Item ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Itemname.ItemId}" Width="80"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Item Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Itemname.Name}" Width="120"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity" Width="100">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox x:Name="txtQuantity" Width="100"  Text="{Binding Path=Qantity, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Purchase Rate" Width="0" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PurchasePrice}" ></GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

Qantity is a property as defined below:

```
    public int Quantity;
    public int Qantity
    {
        get 
        { 
            return Quantity; 
        }
        set
        {
            Quantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Qantity");
        }
    }
```

Anyone please help.

Comment: Check out the answer from user3206784. Where is this "Qantity" property located? Is it in the class makes`lstSelectedStocks` list, or is it in the viewmodel of the control that has contains the ListView? It should be in the class, not the viewmodel.

Comment: This "Qantity" property not in `lstSelectedStocks` list.The quantity is a new property. I want to add the quantity of a particular item.

Comment: ie,how to get the value of a text box inside the grid, and it's not in the ItemSource. I want to edit the text box and entering values like 10. and so that value ie,10 add to the new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood you correctly (correct me if not), but based on your comments, I am guessing you want to add a quantity to a specific item.

If this is the case, your item class will still need to have a quantity property/field to contain this value, but you will probably want to display that property using something like a label if you don't need to be able to set that quantity directly.

You should add this attribute to your ListBox in xaml:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
```

And to your viewmodel you need to add property called "SelectedItem" of the same type as the items in your list.

So lets say in your viewmodel you have:

```
public List<Product> lstSelectedStocks
{
    // ...
}
```

This new property should be:

```
public Product SelectedItem
{
    // ...
}
```

Now add a new TextBox completely outside the ListBox:

You already have "Qantity" property in your viewmodel, so there no more work here.

Also add a new button beside the TextBox;

```
<Button Content="Add Quantity" Command="{Binding Path=AddQuantity}" />
```

And you need to implement "AddQuantity" command in your viewmodel.

To add a quantity to a specific item, you need to do the following steps:

1. select an item in ListBox by clicking on its row - this will set the "SelectedItem" property in your viewmodel
2. enter the amount in the TextBox - this will set your "Quantity" property in your viewmodel
3. press the "Add Quantity" button - this will call the "AddQuantity" command in your view model which should take the value in "Qantity" property and add that value to the SelectedItem.Quantity.

**[Edit based on comment below]**

You could have the TextBox and the "AddQuantity" button on each row in the GridView.

First you would need to move this "Quantity" property to the class that implements each item. I would probably rename this to "QuantityToAdd" or something like that to avoid confusion with quantity that (probably) already exists in the item class.
You would also need to move "AddQuantity" command inside. This way you would always add value in "Qantity" (or "QuantityToAdd" if you renamed it) from that specific item, and there would probably be no need for `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"` in your ListView.
There is probably a more elegant solution, but this is what came to mind at this moment.

Comment: thank you, sir there is any solution for the text box set to inside the grid view.? ie, TextBox completely inside .

Answer (score 0):

Binding Path you assigned to Text property is fine. Only thing you need to check Quantity Property is part of the class which you assigned to gridview itemssource as a collection.